# index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3 (python)

Tags: python

So i looked it up a couple of times and i just cant figure it out so I think it would be best to ask for some help.So here is the deal t0 is a [1000,1], x is a [1000,1] and y is a [1000,1], m=1000, suma1=0 and every time i run it i get this stupid error 
index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

```
for i in range(m):
        suma1+=((t0[i] + x[i]- y[i])**2)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the first index of a list is `0` so `1000` isn't a valid index for a list containing `1000` elements because the last index is `999`. See [OBOE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

Comment: @MSeifert range(1000) gives 0 through 999 so that is not the problem

Comment: Please add more code. Especially the definition of t0, x and y. Because it seems that it is the problem.

Comment: The problem here is a bit different but his/her `t0 = [1000,1]` so it's a 2 element list! So it's the off-by-997-error!

Answer (score 0):

Note that  t0 is a [1000,1], x is a [1000,1] and y is a [1000,1] This means that each of these values is a two dimensional list. However, the code that you are showing appears to want a single dimensioned list summing up the values.

If t0, x, y are two dimensioned lists, then you are concatenating the lists and not adding the values.

```
t0 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 1], [[9, 8, 7, 6], 2]
x = [[8, 7, 4, 7], 3], [[6, 4, 2, 8], 4]
t0[1] + x[1] = [[9, 8, 7, 6], 2, [6, 4, 2, 8], 4]]
```

To do the arithmatic you need singly dimensioned arrays such as:

```
t0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = [8, 7, 4, 7, 1]
y = [3, 7, 9, 4, 8]
```

You need to show more code and show sample values (using m with a range of 10)

Also run your code as individual lines

```
suma1 = 0
for i in range(m):
    suma1 += ((t0[i] + x[i]- y[i])**2)
```

Answer (score -1):

are x, y and t0 1D numpy arrays or what?
Try to find out how to correctly index those arrays?/lists? in the correct way. For example 
t0[999,1] vs t0[1,999]

Edit: 
In that case I would try using:

```
suma1+=((t0[i,1] + x[i,1]- y[i,1])**2)
```

or

```
suma1+=((t0[1,i] + x[1,i]- y[1,i])**2)
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.